# Creating new request services

Tags: ros-groovy, rosservice, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am struggling with creating new requests dynamically.  I have defined my own messages and I want to do something like  `request.setTask("xyz");`  The request will happily take whatever I pass to it if I hardcode the tasks, but I want to have a separate function that I can call and will generate these responses.  Do I need to create a ServiceManager and ServiceFactory?

This:

```
final rosd_messages.RosDRequest request = serviceClient.newMessage();
request.setTask("xyz");
```

works fine.  However, what if we have another task "abc" that we want to execute?  What if we aren't sure how many requests there will be? I can create a new request, but I can't initialize it to serviceClient.newMessage();  as the serviceClient is final.

Any help?

Thanks!
James

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60548/creating-new-request-services/) by [jforkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/4213/jforkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've managed to achieve this by starting my third party application (where the requests derive from) in a separate thread then making the thread wait when you issue the request using:

```
synchronized (thread1) {
    thread1.wait();
 }
```

Then, wake it up in the onSuccess (and onFailure - don't want it getting stuck waiting) with:

```
  synchronized (thread1) {
      thread1.notifyAll();
  }
```

Then I created a method to construct the requests that my third party client can call:

```
 public static void buildRequest(String str){
    
    final rosd_messages.RosDRequest req;
    req = node1.getServiceRequestMessageFactory().newFromType(rosd_messages.RosD._TYPE);
    req.setTask(str);
     ServiceClient<rosd_messages.RosDRequest, rosd_messages.RosDResponse> sClient;
     
    try {
        sClient = node1.newServiceClient("abc123", rosd_messages.RosD._TYPE);
      } catch (ServiceNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RosRuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Note:  There is no reason you have to use custom requests.  I think this gives you the ability to build your own requests dynamically in a fairly efficient way.  If you have a better idea, I am all ears.

Cheers!
-James

---

Originally posted by [jforkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/4213/jforkey/) with karma: 82 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0